# (no-answer) How do I merge videos that have overlapping frames into a video without duplicate frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, shell-script, video-editing, vbscript, opencv

I've nvidia highlights that takes 3 minutes recordings when events happen. If two events happen sooner than 3 minutes then those recorded clips have overlapping frames. I want to take all the clips and merge them into one video using command line.

I can merge all videos using ffpmeg but it can't tell if videos are overlapping.

Comment: So, not a great solution, but it is possible to export all the frame of a video as static images and then de-duplicate from there. That said, I think the big issue with this approach (besides possibly time and space concerns) would be making sure any audio was properly edited and re-synced.

Comment: one suggestion i have received is to use opencv to calculate overlapping frames points and then using ffmpeg splice videos and then merge

Comment: Related: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/concat-overlapping-videos-with-ffmpeg-using-python3/24689